How to check wether two mean values are significantly different?
I have two distributions with a size of ~120 and ~86.000 elements. I would like to check wether the mean value of the two distributions are significantly different.
I found, that I can use a Welch’s t-test for that, but this test still requires that the distributions are normal.
I used scipy.stats.normaltest() to check if they are a normal distribution, but the tests failed. However, I read that the test will almost always fail for large sample sizes and that the distributions don't have to be exactly normal.
How can I check if my distributions are good enough for a Welch’s t-test or are there any other methods than a t-test that I can use to determine wether the mean values of my two distributions are significantly different?
Here are the distributions in question:


You can try using the Mann–Whitney U test. It can be applied to non-normal distributions (it is a non-parametric test). It does make some assumptions, however, that you need to check:

The observations are independent.
The observations are ordinal (comparable).

Implementation: scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.

If I understand this test correctly, it does not directly test wether the two medians are equal, but rather if the values of the first distribution are higher/lower than the values of the second distribution? If so, that would be fine for me.

Yeah, it won't tell exactly about the means/medians, but you can use it to compare two groups of non-normal data.
